# Is there a way to redirect from a URL to a page with parameters without changing the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hi I'm creating a website, and I find myself editing the `.htaccess` file. I have made several attempts to redirect from a URL like `/isexistinguser` to `/api/usermanager?type=1` without changing the address visible in the browser but still can't find a solution. Is there someone who can help me?

This is what I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /isexistinguser [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /api/usermanager?type=1 [NC,L,R]
```

The problems here are two:

- the address changes on redirection
- Any URL that contains `/isexistinguser` is considered in the condition, for example `/isexistinguserblabla`

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far? Thanks

Comment: This is not possible the way you try to. What you could do instead is keep a page framework in the client (so _not_ doing a full page reload) and perform an internal ajax request to fetch that URL and visualize the response in the still loaded page.

Comment: I hope I was clearer with this change @AmitVerma

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are suggesting to me. However I would like this redirect not to be visible to the user.@arkascha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.
Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(isexistinguser)$ api/usermanager?type=1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the second problem still arises. I wish it didn't work with `/isexistinguserblabla`. @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @IvanCisternino, for any url like `http:localhost:80/isexistinguser` OR `http:localhost:80/isexistinguserblaba` URLs since I am checking condition like URL should start with `isexistinguser` do ideally it should work, please let me know on same thank you.

Comment: It works, but I wish the check wasn't just for the start, it should also end like this. The url must also end with `/isexistinguser` and there must be nothing after it @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @IvanCisternino, ok, could you please do check my edit once and let me know if this helps you? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: I changed your last solution and I did it, thank you very much! Maybe you can put it in your answer to help someone else.
`RewriteRule ^(isexistinguser)$ api/usermanager?type=1 [NC,L]`
@RavinderSingh13